# MultiPolygon Intersect only working for first Polygon in collection, how can I fix this?

Tags: postgis, geojson, st-intersects

I am very new to PostGIS.

I have a table called regions, that has name, an id and a geojson that is a MultiPolygon.

Now I need to check whether certain points or other MultiPolygon regions intersect with it.

This is my sql statement:

```
SELECT regions.id, name
        FROM regions
        WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(
          regions.geom,
            ST_SetSRID(ST_Makepoint(lat,long), 3857));
```

This works fine for the first Polygon of the MultiPolygon of a region. But if I check if a point/MP intersects with any of the other MultiPolygons within a region it returns nothing.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at ST_Dump?

Comment: No, I haven't yet, taking a look now